# Showing blinking cursor in unfocused text input

Tags: javascript, html

I need to do this without any hack. Thanks.

Comment: What do you consider a hack?  Would a blinking pipe `|` character in the input field suffice?

Comment: will code for food

Comment: I would LOVE to hear why you would want to confuse users, unless you want to simulate a caret while inserting stuff yourself. That can be done in a div/span too

Comment: Open a second browser tab. While in the first tab the cursor is blinking, you can go to the second. The first will stay unfocused and blinking :)

Comment: This could be useful for fishing.

Comment: Yes, I want to do some phishing!

Comment: LOL! good luck with that. I'm sure it will be the first ever successful phishing attack based on StackOverflow questions. :-)

Comment: I've got this problem right now: I want to be able to leave the caret when other buttons have the focus. Here the example: You have an input with an on-screen keyboard. When moving with the keys on the letters, you want to keep the caret blinking. So, nothing suspicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this without some sort of hackery.

Here's a simple pure CSS hack:

```
input {
  background-image:     url(cursor-anim.gif);
  background-position:  4px 50%;
}
input:focus {
  background-image: none;
}
```

But, as others have said, It might be worth asking yourself if this may lead to your users getting confused...

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a pipe (|) in a blink tag (ugh) and position it absolutely over a text input!

Seriously though, don't confuse gentle users :)

Comment: As per [MDN's Recommendation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blink): **Warning:** Do not use this element as it is non-standard and **deprecated.** Blinking text is frowned upon by several accessibility standards and the CSS specification allows browsers to ignore the blink value. **Almost all browsers currently ignore this element.**